# Adding Conversation Participant using Postman

Tags: twilio, postman, twilio-api, twilio-conversations

I'm trying to use Twilio Conversations for a project, and in order to just get a simple understanding of everything I'm trying to tinker it out in Postman first. I'm trying to create a conversation Participant there but I keep getting Error 5204 - Identity not Provided.

I've tried to give an identity as a parameter, or an element in the body, as well as the same for the two needed fields for an SMS participant.

Comment: Are you able to fetch your conversation with a `GET 'https://conversations.twilio.com/v1/Conversations/CHXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'` where `CHXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX` is your conversation sid?

Comment: Getting is absolutely fine, I can also POST new conversations, it's just Participants that aren't working.

Comment: Are you able to `Create Conversation Participant (SMS)` for which you only need to provide your Twilio number and participant's number? (maybe try with cURL https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/api/conversation-participant-resource?code-sample=code-create-conversation-participant-sms&code-language=curl&code-sdk-version=json)

Comment: No luck with that in Postman, but it worked fin in cURL. Any idea what I'm doing wrong in Postman? I've tried putting the binding addresses as both fields in body and parameters?

Comment: @gehrlich you could convert the request you are sending via postman into curl as found here https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/generate-code-snippets/. You could then compare them both to find the issue !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the problem is not at Twilio because it works with cURL.

If you want to do it with Postman, select the **"Body"** tab and make sure you choose **`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`** so the content-type header will automatically be set for you.

Then add the key/values pairs, but to create a (SMS) participant you only need to add a Twilio number and a participant number.

---

Just tried on my computer and it works no problem.

[image]

---

Update from @gehrlich: sounds like **the keys are case sensitive!**

Comment: Still gives error 50204, despite not referencing identity anywhere.

Comment: Updated answer with image, what can I say, just make sure you have the right values for `https://conversations.twilio.com/v1/Conversations/CHXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Participants` and phone numbers.

Comment: Worked! To any future readers, the reason was the capitalization. Twilio's documentation has messagingbindinging.address and .proxyaddress all lowercase, but you need those capital letters.